# How to integrate messages or outputs from Model layer into a templated page

Tags: php, model-view-controller, template-engine, separation-of-concerns

I am working on templating in PHP. I know there are templating engines out there but i want something simple for a small project.
Here is my problem:

Most of my output are stored in a variable $contents and assigned to the template to display in the content section of my page

But sometimes i have echo("blah blah") in my Model [like in case of exception, query failure] and i want to pass that to my page.

problem is this output shows before the page e.g.

```
$contents = "I want to show this";

$news = $news->getNews();

//concatenate
$contents = $contents.''.[resultsfromnews]

$template = new Template();
$template->content = $contents; //and so on
$template->display();
```

if `$news->getNews()` method or the methods it calls echoes something e.g. ('database specific error, exception), they show before the `$template->display()` is called

> *Custom error information/notification from `getNews()` showing here before page content*
>
> **Normal Page Content**
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse
>   molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at
>   vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent
>   luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
>   Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil
>   imperdiet doming id

Please help me with a solution... how those output could be part of my content to display.

I feel this issue could occur with all the popular template engines out there (Smarty, Twig, phpsavant etc) - how was it taken care of?

**I have been searching for awhile to know how it works in other template engines - have not got close **

Thanks

Comment: If you want something simple and small for your project, let me suggest you [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/).

Comment: I have seen that before but didn't have the time to go through. Will that handle custom message written out from somewhere else - like mentioned in the question

Comment: Yes, you can assign variables. You can also make use of output buffering by the way, probably that is what you're looking for? http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: that looks interesting. I am looking into that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
$contents = "I want to show this";    

ob_start();
$news = $news->getNews();
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//concatenate
$contents = $contents.$buffer.''.[resultsfromnews]

$template = new Template();
$template->content = $contents; //and so on
$template->display();
```

However, one should not be echoing within models. It is better to throw exceptions and catch them just before setting the output.